# Achemso suppinfo environment formatting for communication

Tags: achemso

I am writing a manuscript using the achemso package in the communication style. However, when i use the suppinfo environment, the text size of "Supporting information available" stays as big as it would be in the "article" style (see attached picture).

[image]

How can i get this to format correctly?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. WHat did you try?

Comment: The problem basically occurs when I use `\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=communication]{achemso}
\begin{suppinfo}
\end{suppinfo}`

I am using Overleaf.

Comment: What do you mean 'properly': the `achemso` class never tries to match the typeset output of the journals (which is not done in LaTeX).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! i realise that I don't do the final format, it just looks sore to the eye in the manuscript. The acknowledgement section before the "supporting information available" is adjusted accordingly when changing the manuscript type from article to communication, after all.